# updated Rstudio and R, now unable to install rjags

Tags: r, rjags, r2jags

I just updated Rstudio (2023.03.0 Build 386) and R (R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt) -- "Shortstop Beagle"). I am trying to install rjags, R2jags, and simmR. Everything else is dependent on rjags.

When intstalling rjags I get the error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/hglassic/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/rjags/libs/x64/rjags.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
```

When navigating to the folder, the date modified is 4/3/23, today, the day I updated all of the versions of Rstudio & R. I can open and run JAGS without error.

I am on a windows machine. I have looked at the JAGS website and other questions on stackoverflow and cannot find my issue or the potential solution.

Comment: Is it possible that your install.packages is looking for a local package? Looks like the message is looking for local. I just updated to the latest R and Rstudio and installed `rjags` with no problem.

Comment: What Windows version are you using?

Comment: @MrFlick Windows 10 Enterprise version 22H2

Comment: @markhogue if it is, how can I change where it is looking? Would you be willing to share your folder sequence so I can see if I could mimic that on my machine?

Comment: What version of `jags` do you have installed?

Comment: @MrFlick 4.3.0 is installed

Comment: It looks like you need 4.3.1 in Windows if you are using R 4.2+ https://martynplummer.wordpress.com/2022/04/12/windows-update-jags-4-3-1-is-released/

Comment: @MrFlick that was it. What a noob move. Thanks.